# Regular Expression from csv like to php array declaration

Tags: regex, preg-replace, pcre

Is there a way, using a regular expression (or few regular expressions in cascade), to convert a csv like text into something similar to a php array declaration, having an arbitrary number of fields?

For instance, the regular expression should go from this:

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 ...
value1 value2 value3 value4 ...
```

to this:

```
"field1" => "value1",
"field2" => "value2",
"field3" => "value3",
"field4" => "value4",
...
```

Is that possible using just regular expressions? Do you have suggestions about a practical implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do multiple search and replaces that search for `^ *(\w+)(.*)\r\n *(\w+)` and replace with `!\1=\3\r\n\2\r\n`, assuming Windows style line endings. Then run another simple edit to remove the leading `!` characters. Using the example from the question

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 ...
value1 value2 value3 value4 ...
```

The first replacement yields:

```
!field1=value1
 field2 field3 field4 ...
 value2 value3 value4 ...
```

The next replacement yields:

```
!field1=value1
!field2=value2
 field3 field4 ...
 value3 value4 ...
```

After two more replacements it completes leaving:

```
!field1=value1
!field2=value2
!field3=value3
!field4=value4
 ...
 ...
```

The remaining edits would need to tidy up `!` and the `.` characters.

The search string allows optional spaces at the beginning of the line the `^ *`.
It then looks for a field-name `(\w+)` and the rest of that line `(.*)` and a line separator `\r\n`.
Next it looks for optional spaces then a field-value with `*(\w+)`.

The replacement just reorders the found fields and adds a leading `!` so that a subsequent replace-all operation will not find thefields already matched.

Not exactly sure how to map this on to PHP, but it works fine in Notepad++ version 6.5.5.

Comment: I'll try this! Just be careful: the dots imply more fields, not just dots

Comment: The idea is good, but the regexp just doesn't work... have you tried it under a pcre environment?

Comment: @clami219 have you used the "correct" line endings for your PCRE version? (Note that PCRE has many meanings.)

Comment: PCRE stands for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. Anyway, you are right, the problem was with the line endings! Good job!

Comment: @clami219 I meant that there are several systems that claim to provide PCREs but they all provide slightly different facilities. I am happy that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with pure regex. But you can do it in PHP with arrays simply:

```
$text = "field1 field2 field3 field4 ...
          value1 value2 value3 value4 ...";

$arr = explode("\n", $text);

$field = explode(' ', $arr[0]);
$value = explode(' ', $arr[1]);
```

Then you can use a foreach loop to do this

Comment: That's not how you use functions in PHP. `$arr = explode("\n", $text);`, but anyway this wouldn't help the OP.